# HTML Form constrain by JavaScript--number issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am writing a form to ask for input for lower and upper limit of weight range and to return the objects within the weight range. In order to prevent user entering lower limit>upper limit(eg. lower limit=5 and upper limit=2), I used the javascript below.
When testing, the form is generating expected result when both upper limit and lower limit are less than 10.
However, it returns "lower limit greater than upper limit" error message when i try on 
lower=2/upper=10 or lower=9/upper=10
In addition, when i try lower=2 and upper=30, it works again. (I am using Chrome for testing)
Seems it is only comparing the first digit of the lower and upper input.
Not sure if it is caused by incorrect input type or Javascript. Can anyone help to resolve the problem?
Thanks

HTML5 FORM:

```
<label>Please enter lower limit: <input type="number" name="weightl" 
step="0.00000000001" min="0" id="weightl" autofocus required   
placeholder="Accepts decimal places"/></label>

<label>Please enter upper limit:<input type="number" name="weightu"
step="0.00000000001" min="0" id="weightu" autofocus required 
placeholder="Accepts decimal places"/></label>

<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("weightl").onchange = validateWeight;
document.getElementById("weightu").onchange = validateWeight;
}
function validateWeight(){
var up=document.getElementById("weightu").value;
var low=document.getElementById("weightl").value;

if(low>up)
document.getElementById("weightu").setCustomValidity("Upper limit has to be equal or greater than lower limit");
else
document.getElementById("weightu").setCustomValidity('');  
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere "lower limit greater than upper limit" in your JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not numbers.

```
if (+low > +up)
```

would be one way to fix that.

The "value" property of a form field will always be a string. JavaScript string comparison does not automatically treat strings as numbers just because they look like numbers. Preceding the variable reference with a `+` forces conversion to numbers. There are other ways of doing it:

```
if (Number(low) > Number(up))
```

or

```
if (parseFloat(low) > parseFloat(up))
```

etc.